# How to add ngx_http_auth_request_module to nginx-unprivileged

Tags: nginx

I need to validate an OAuth token on NGINX (nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.25) before a proxy_pass is done.

I understand that I need to add or enable the [ngx_http_auth_request_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html#auth_request) to be able to validate the token with the auth server. I have no idea how to do this.

What I got so far is this:

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.25

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential

# Get the NGINX source code
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN apt-get source nginx

# Build NGINX with the desired module
WORKDIR /tmp/nginx-*
RUN ./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=/path/to/ngx_http_auth_request_module
RUN make modules

# Copy the compiled module to the appropriate location
RUN cp objs/ngx_http_auth_request_module.so /etc/nginx/modules
```

I have no idea where to get the ngx_http_auth_request_module source from or the ngx_http_auth_request_module.so On GitHub I found this [ngx_http_auth_request_module.c](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_auth_request_module.c) which is c file. Is this considered the source.

Sorry I am a bit of a rookie on modifying NGINX. Any idea how to implement this or another way to validate the auth token or a step in the right direction.